# How to make props work inside an image tag directly while using "require"?

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing the image source like this:

```
<Card img="card-1.png" />
```

```
function Card(props){
   return(
       <img src={require(props.img)} alt="card1" />
   )
```

This is giving me "Cannot find module 'card-1.png'" error.

It is working if I put the image url directly like this:

```
function Card(props){
   return(
       <img src={require("card-1.png")} alt="card1" />
   )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try "Template literals"

```
<img src={require(`${props.img}`)} alt="card1" />
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).